# Using local const

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I installed resharper and it suggested to me that I should modify some local variables to a const. I never heard of this, so I starting googling. MSDN sure enough has a bit of code of having local consts, but no explanation why. On stackoverflow I came across questions but had more to do with whether having a local const is faster than not having them.

So, I'm scratching my head here. Why is it possible to have a local const? Does it have to do with semantics? Is there some benefit? Maybe both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Const have a main benefit: it's value is unchangeable and this enforce code stability and solidness.

Let's say you've to define some date format during some method execution and it's valid for this one only. Why don't you'd be using a constant?

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    const string dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";

    ... // Lot of operations


    return Date.Now.ToString(dateFormat);
}
```

You avoid human errors if you use constants if it's possible to use them.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was just in the mind set of (e.g. let's take your example) that dateFormat would not change anyway because it doesn't seem so hard to loose track of dateFormat and accidentally attaching another value to it, because it is in a method.

Comment: Yeah, but you know how we're humans... We do errors, we're far from perfection haha

Answer (score 1):

Having a local const is simply a matter of scoping. Instead of the const being available to the entire class or consumers of that class (if the const is public) it is only available in the method where you declare it.

To demonstrate why ReSharper suggest the refactoring I have included the generated IL for a simple example.

Without const:

```
string s = "foo";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Generated IL:

```
ldstr       "foo"
stloc.0     
ldloc.0     
call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

With const:

```
const string s = "foo";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Generated IL:

```
ldstr       "foo"
call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

Comment: A value will have the same scope regardless of whether it is a local variable, or a local const (both are declared within a method).

Comment: @Fredrik - I think he's drawing a contrast between a local const and non-local (e.g. class level) const - which is probably where most people are familiar with seeing the const keyword (in C#)

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Yes, and I'm trying to answer the question _Why is it possible to have a local const?_

Comment: OK, I understood the question as being about the difference between local variable and local const (*"[...]that I should modify some local variables to a const. /.../ Why is it possible to have a local const? Does it have to do with semantics? Is there some benefit?"*). Coming from that angle, I got a bit confused by the scoping discussion.

Comment: :-) I did mean local variable and local const, the scope being a method, as in `SomeMethod() { int y = 10 } `and `SomeMethod() { const int y = 10 }. `I didn't mean the scope being method/class. I am sorry for any confusion, I picked up the terminology local const from googling.